# Microsoft SQL Server Rows to Column Transpose using PiVOT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-sql

I'm using MS-SQLServer-2016 and got a requirement to transpose rows to columns. 
I'm using Pivot and dynamic SQL option to do it because the number of rows is dynamic.
Figure1 is the output I'm currently getting. However the client doesn't want those NULLs displayed. He only wants the Not-Null dates to be displayed.
Is there way to get rid of those Null Values and display only distinct dates?

[Figure1-Transpose_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC9CK.jpg)

With Regards,

Tanuja

```
DECLARE @columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @var1 AS 
VARCHAR(MAX); 

SELECT @columns = stuff((select DISTINCT ',' + quotename(replace(replace(replace(n.action_note,' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ') )
                         from engagement_action n, action_party m, personal p
                         where n.action_id = m.action_id
                           and p.party_id = m.party_id
                           and n.action_note like 'XXX'
                           and m.system_name = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
                           and p.customer_number = 'XXXXXXX' FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SELECT @sql =

              'select "RANK_IN_PROP" ,
               customer_number, 
               customer_shortname, 
               system_name,
               '+ @columns + '
               from
                   (SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY convert(date,m.created_when) ORDER BY convert(date,m.created_when))"RANK_IN_PROP" ,
                          p.customer_number,
                          p.customer_shortname, 
                          m.system_name,
                          m.created_when ,
                          convert(date,m.created_when) as created_when, 
                          replace(replace(replace(n.action_note,'' '',''<>''),''><'',''''),''<>'','' '') as action_note1 
                   FROM engagement_action n, action_party m, personal p
                  WHERE n.action_id = m.action_id
                    AND p.party_id = m.party_id
                    AND n.action_note like ''%XXX%'' 
                    AND m.system_name = ''XXXXXXXXXXX''
                    AND p.customer_number = ''XXXXXXXX'' ) d
                  PIVOT 
                     (max(created_when) for action_note1 in ( ' + @columns + ' ))p order by created_when desc'

execute(@sql);`
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: why don't you create a Table Based on Row result set of Actual Table you are using.

Comment: You need to reduce the `from (select ...)` to just the columns you want `pivot()` along with columns to pivot by. Then join to the result of your `pivot()` to add in all those other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this , just added (select distinct action_note engagement_action where action_note is not null)  in where clause. As i can't create test data so could not really execute the query

```
SELECT @columns = stuff((select DISTINCT ',' + 
quotename(replace(replace(replace(n.action_note,' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ') 
)
                     from 
                     (select distinct action_note engagement_action where action_note is not null) 
                     n, action_party m, personal p
                     where n.action_id = m.action_id
                       and p.party_id = m.party_id
                       and n.action_note like 'XXX'
                       and m.system_name = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
                       and p.customer_number = 'XXXXXXX' FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```

Comment: Hi Srinivasa Rao, I tried it I'm getting the same output. The thing is even if I say distinct of action_note in the place where you said, I'll only end up with distinct column names when these rows are getting transposed. It will not affect the dates in anyway.